# Why does Haskell ignore the hard coded int in this example?

Tags: haskell

Why does this only evaluate to x?:

```
(digitToInt (head (evalE x 0))) + 100
```

evalE x 0 evaluates to a string representation of x. The head part converts x to a Char, while the digitToInt turns it into an integer.

I would expect it to evaluate to (x + 100), but it's always just x. Why is that?

Here is the context of the evaluation:

```
import Data.Char(digitToInt)

data Ast
    = Num Int
    | Plus Ast Ast
    deriving (Eq, Show)

evalE (Num i) acc = show i

evalE (Plus x y) acc = if (isDigit (head (evalE x 0))) && (isDigit (head (evalE y 0))) then show ((digitToInt (head (evalE x 0))) + 100) else evalE x 0
```

If I do "evalE (Num 1) 0", I get "1" as the output.

Comment: You should include the implementations. It is not possible to really tell what's going on from what you've given so far. Also, I would only expect the thing you described to result in `x + 100` if `x` is an integer between `0` and `9` (I don't know if this is relevant to the problem here, though).

Comment: @David I will add the implementation as well. The integer is always between 0 and 9.

Comment: Which case of `evalE`'s pattern match do you think will be used when you evaluate `evalE (Num 1) 0` and why?

Comment: @David Hahaha, thanks. This is why you shouldn't program at 4 am. I'm not too familiar with Stackoverflow etiquette, should I delete the question? With the amount of debugging I performed, this honestly embarrassing.

Comment: You may answer your own question now that you've figured it out. Since you didn't get any answers, deletion is also an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing "evalE (Num 1) 0" will pattern match

```
evalE (Num i) acc = show i
```

so the

```
(digitToInt (head (evalE x 0))) + 100
```

is never executed, as it would require pattern matching to

```
evalE (Plus x y) acc = if (isDigit (head (evalE x 0))) && (isDigit (head (evalE y 0))) then show ((digitToInt (head (evalE x 0))) + 100) else evalE x 0
```